# Row Fill using last value in impala SQL

Tags: sql, analytics, impala

I have a requirement when I need to fill in rows for item number using the last item number value assigned to a document number.

For example:

If document number is `1001` and document item number 10 the values for item number in the rows below display a `NA` and I need to fill those in using 10, the value above.
I have tried `LEAD` and `LAG` but it still gives me `NULLS` in some cases.

Attached is some sample data for reference:

[image]